# How can a convert an image into a url?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, imageurl

I am creating a web app, in which I receive a image file from the user then have to store it in my Firebase Realtime Database and display it in Html. Since Realtime Database doesn't support files I have to create a Url for my image.

The Url I want is not a download link like [this](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/connectify-21b27.appspot.com/o/ZT.png?alt=media&token=fc791c84-d124-41ba-be1b-ddba04eb1cab) which I got from the Firebase Cloud Storage Url creation tool, rather I need a viewable link like [this](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg) which I can add to the src on my  tag in Html like this:

```
<img src="The Url">
```

I have tried using Firebase Cloud Storage, but when uploading and image file, the image is uploaded as an Application/octate-stream rather than an image. When I run the geturl() function it gives me [this link](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/connectify-21b27.appspot.com/o/ZT.png?alt=media&token=fc791c84-d124-41ba-be1b-ddba04eb1cab) which leads to a download page and therefore I cannot it to the src attribute of  tag.

The file uploading code is this:

```
var file_from_usr = document.getElementById('file_input')
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var thisRef = storageRef.child(filename);
thisRef.put(file_from_usr).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

Comment: convert your image binary data into base64 string

Comment: how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a metadata issue to me. Your code is not able to infer the file's type, so by default, it will assume it to be an Application/octet-stream content type.

if for some reason your filename has no extension or some other problems then you can manually specify that content-type metadata.

```js
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

// Upload the file and metadata
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/mountains.jpg').put(file, metadata);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Alternatively, try putting an extension to your filename . eg. filename= "myimage.jpg"

Comment: Using this the file gets uploaded as an image but then I think it gets corrupted.  [This](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/connectify-21b27.appspot.com/o/sample.jpg?alt=media&token=e9da76f7-4a18-441c-a32d-d621726b6bea) is the link I get

Comment: Try uploading a different image. Also , Converting your image to base64 encoding (text formatis not an efficient way to upload  files.

Answer (score 0):

download image data using fetch api and convert it into url which you can set to image src attribute; `Added the code snippet for the same below`.
This code is to download image and skipped the upload task which seems like working as mentioned in above post.

```
getImageURL(url) {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    cache: 'default'
  };
  return fetch(url, options).then((response) => {
    return response.blob();
  }).then(blob => {
    return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  });
}

document.getElementById("myImg").src = getImageURL("https://{your_url_path}");
```

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand what are you trying to say. I am a new to Javascript. How can I download image data using fetch api and convert it into a url?

Comment: you need to call getImageURL() method by passing the url, and it will get the response as blob and will convert to url.

Comment: Oh ok. Now I get it. I will try and respond

Comment: This is giving me this error:

Access to fetch at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/connectify-21b27.appspot.com/o/sample.jpg?alt=media&token=ce0cd892-a92f-4103-ba08-dbe7994d24fe' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: you need to disable cors to make it work from your local machine

Comment: so if I distribute my app it wouldn't work then

Comment: your app and server should be in the same origin or you need to disable cors. Read this link for details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Comment: update code by setting "no-cors", try once

Comment: I disabled cors and then I get this "blob:http://127.0.0.1:5500/8e8654fd-7cbf-4d1d-93be-cf66d084a726" which leads to a download page